# Is there a way to connect to UltraVNC server and use built-in file transfer in Linux

Tags: linux, file-transfer, ultravnc

Is there a Linux VNC client that can use UltraVNC server's file transfer option? I tried my KDE default KRDC and Remmina, Java client TightVNC ... I tried to install UltraVNC client via wine also. No luck.

Comment: Yes. In Chrome and Firefox. In a tab, it shows PC's name and only empty white page with ultravnc web page link. Java plug-in problem? On server java http view enabled on port 5800.

Comment: I will try. For now no luck running that old Firefox on a system where I have Firefox Quantum already. I get an error when trying to run esr on 64bit Kubuntu with multiarch: x@probook6470b:~/Downloads/firefox$ ./firefox-bin 
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /home/x/Downloads/firefox/libxul.so:
libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
x@probook6470b:~/Downloads/firefox$ sudo ./run-mozilla.sh
run-mozilla.sh: Cannot execute .

Comment: If I do that, Firefox Quantum 58.0.2 from path is being executed.

Comment: I did I got this error: x@probook6470b:~/Downloads/firefox$ ./firefox -P
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /home/x/Downloads/firefox/libxul.so:
libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Couldn't load XPCOM. Is it because I have a newer library?